# Getting parameters on Laravel from an Axios Post Request Body

Tags: php, laravel, axios, http-post

Im currently working on a Laravel APP and one of the endpoints is a method that receives an Axios Post Request from a React APP with some parameters.

On laravel i only need to get those Post Resquest Parameters to save them on a database but im not figure how i get only the values.

Im using Postman to test it and im sending on the body a value '1234567890' with the value 'param', something like this:

```
axios.post("/myendpoint", {
  param: '1234567890',
});
```

and on Laravel im doing this (as i've seen on another stackoverflow question):

```
public function myendpointmethod(Request $request)
    {
       return response()->json($request->param);
    }
```

but this only returns me an empty array.

Im using Laravel Framework 7.25.0.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this working with postman?

Comment: Postman only returns an empty array.

Comment: Btw, in my controller if i return, for example, a string, it works fine. Im just not getting the post body parameters.

Comment: Try only return $request->params without the response or json method and check if you getting anything in postman

Comment: Blank response.

Comment: Check return isset($request->param);